# Amateur code protection procedure

Tags: security

as the title suggests, I am interested in how "good" this procedure is, if I wanted to create a trial version of my program which allows the user to run it for a certain time, until it reaches its expiration date. Also, a typical user will not be a specially "computer-literate" person - I think this is an important assumption here.

So, here is a pseudo-code:

```
at program installation:

    write encrypted (time_left = infinity) to registry

at every program run:

    calculate time_left = licence_limit_time - current_time
    (if registry.time_left doesnt extst)
        abort program
    (else)
        (if time_left >= registry.time_left)
            abort program
        (else)
            write time_left to registry
```

The first step at program installation ensures that deletion of the registry key will yield the program unusable.

The point of this procedure is that it should be immune (unless I'm missing something big here) to the user simply changing the system time.

Any comments and suggestions are highly welcome.

Edit: also, an assumption is that the program is compiled.

Comment: Check online date when user is connected to internet

Comment: Lorenzo, thanks, although I have already thought of that - I only plan to implement it if an "internet-independent" approach could succeed.

Comment: If the computer-illiterate person is able to delete registry keys, I think it should likely be able to copy a registry key and copy back the value later (known as replay attack in encryption community).

Comment: To be honest, I think I'm thinking far ahead of myself. The typical user I will be dealing with probably even does not know how to enter the system registry

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's the point of `time_left >= registry.time_left`. If you can calculate the time_left, then you don't need the registry copy of it. If you trust the registry copy, then you don't need to calculate. Both of them don't really improve anything.

Specifically, rolling back the registry key and the date will workaround your protection.

That was the answer. Here's the commentary on the idea:

Realistically you're trying to implement a DRM. There's nothing you can do that will work for all cases, you can just delay a determined person for hours. Your time is probably better spent implementing the simplest non-trivial protection (check against date) and improving the product instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The purpose of time_left >= registry.time_left was to check if the system time has been set to an earlier date, since this would contradict normal time flow. I see your point, but does there exist a non-trivial "check against date" protection which is immune to the user simply changing the system time? (of course, with exception of setting internet date and time)

Comment: Without some external process (internet, devices, etc.) - no. You're stuck with what the user provides. The best you could do is save the time at some intervals and check if it ever goes backwards. But that's also trivial to work around - someone can delete that data. Or run a program which monitors monotinic timer against wall clock. But then you just need to kill that program to work around.